# Trying to get informaton from csv file

Tags: java, android, csv

So i tried to get info from csv file and then filter it so i get six random rows which's 17nd column is equal to my string position which I get as an argument while calling function in other activity, the only thing that is not working is my CSV reader, in my logs it says could find file ENOENT, i tried litteraly evrything, but couldnt find solution, hope someone will help me with this

```
 public class PlayerManager {
public static List<List<String>> getSixRandomPlayers(String position) {
    List<List<String>> players = readPlayersFromCSV();
    List<List<String>> filteredPlayers = filterPlayersByPosition(players, position);
    return selectRandomPlayers(filteredPlayers, 6);
}

private static List<List<String>> readPlayersFromCSV() {
    List<List<String>> players = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("raw/players.csv"))) {
        String line;


        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] playerData = line.split(",");
            List<String> player = new ArrayList<>();
            player.add(playerData[0]); // 1st column
            player.add(playerData[2]); // 3rd column
            player.add(playerData[6]); // 7nd column
            player.add(playerData[13]); // 14nd column
            player.add(playerData[7]); // 8th column
            player.add(playerData[16]); // 16nd column
            players.add(player);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return players;
}

private static List<List<String>> filterPlayersByPosition(List<List<String>> players, String position) {
    List<List<String>> filteredPlayers = new ArrayList<>();

    for (List<String> player : players) {
        String playerPosition = player.get(16);
        if (playerPosition.equals(position)) {
            filteredPlayers.add(player);
        }
    }

    return filteredPlayers;
}

private static List<List<String>> selectRandomPlayers(List<List<String>> players, int count) {
    Collections.shuffle(players);
    return players.subList(0, Math.min(count, players.size()));
}
```

}

This is the log
2023-06-09 17:36:22.140 19626-19626/com.samsung.futtrivia W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: raw/players.csv: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: can you share the log

Comment: on the log you will find something like **cant fin file on XX/XXX/XX/raw/players.csv"**
i suggest to move the file to that location XX/XXX/XX/raw/players.csv

Comment: But its in there

Comment: `new FileReader("raw/players.csv")` means "read the file "<user.dir>/raw/players.cvs". "user.dir" is the directory in which the Java virtual machine is started. This is usually *not* your project directory. Try `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"))`. If `raw/players.csv` is part of your project files, you might want to use [Class.getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) instead. And do not use `FileReader`, use `InputStreamReader` with an explicitly specified file encoding.

Comment: As a note, you can use _.._ in the relative path name, also.  So, if it's off by one directory, you can use _"../raw/players.csv"_.

Answer (score 0):

The file is probably not at the location the program expects it.
Try creating a file with the method below, that will give you a clue where to put the input file.

```
    private static void newFileLocation() {
        File test = new File("data.txt");

        try {
            test.createNewFile();
            System.out.println("File created at: " + test.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but where do i put this method?

Comment: Somewhere in your existing code, so that it's called at some point.    
In this example you could insert it into PlayerManager even:    

`private static List<List<String>> readPlayersFromCSV() {  
    newFileLocation();  
  
    List<List<String>> players = new ArrayList<>();  
    return players;  
}  

private static List<List<String>> readPlayersFromCSV2() {
    // original code...
}`

Comment: Sorry for the garbage formatting, I can't figure out linebreaks in this thing.

Comment: @vajnaivik afaik you can't format code in comments. Getting the current directory is much simpler: it's in property `user.dir`